# Where does the term "unsigned integer" come from?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

Many programming languages I've encountered contain multiple integer types, including a distinction between "signed" and "unsigned integers".

I've never heard the term "unsigned integer" before I've gotten into programming, and to me it seems that unsigned integers are equivalent to natural numbers in math (aka ℕ<sub>0</sub>).

So why did we make up the term "unsigned integer" rather then just using the term "natural"? Where did it come from? Is there a valid rationale behind that term or is it just another accident of history?

Comment: Of interest: Signed Number History [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#History)

Comment: I would answer this but the link I gave really does give the answer and link only answers are not allowed. Also coping a large portion of another work and not adding to it has no value just to gain points here.

Comment: naturals does not include zero, but unsigned integers do. Then, mathematicians consider naturals as an infinite set.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: What you're saying is not true: some definitions of natural numbers include 0 and some don't. My question makes it clear I refer to the definition which includes 0. Mathematicians also consider integers to be an infinite set, not only natural numbers. So it's unclear what you're trying to say.

Answer (score -3):

In a *signed* integer, the first bit is a *sign* denoting whether the number is positive or negative. That naturally makes an *unsigned* integer, which lacks said *sign* and cannot distinguish between positive and negative values. "Natural number" would be rather misleading, since a (very) finite integer cannot possibly express anywhere near the full set of natural numbers.

Comment: AFAIK most computer systems use sign bits for floating point numbers only, while integers use two's complement which allows many instructions to be shared between signed and unsigned integers. Also your comment about finite integers not being able to represent the infinite set of natural numbers makes no sense - after all both of the (mathematical) sets - natural and integer numbers -  are infinite and thus not expressible with finite computer memory. Thus, if "natural" would be misleading, so would "integer" be. So this doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: nearly no processor uses a ones-complement for representing signed integer numbers